# Optimizing subselects out of query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL query that cherry picks different pieces of data from different tables to build a report.  Example:

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.first_name,
  u.last_name,
  (select count(*) from monkeys where owner_id = u.id) as pet_monkeys,
  ((select count(*) from speeding_tickets where owner_id = u.id) + (select count(*) from parking_tickets where owner_id = u.id)) as moving_violations,
FROM
  user as u
WHERE
  u.id = 12345
```

In the real code there are about 20 sub-selects pulling statistics from different tables.  This query is also nightmarishly slow.

Is there a better way to organize the above query with a JOIN or a UNION or something?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, they are all linking back to the same table user, you can join them together to group and count, which will be much faster. Also make sure you have correct indices built

```
 SELECT
  u.id,
  max(u.first_name),
  max(u.last_name),
  count(m.owner_id) as pet_monkeys,
  count(s.owner_id) + count(p.owner_id) as moving_violations
FROM
  user as u, monkeys m, speeding_tickets s, parking_tickets p
WHERE
  u.id = 12345 and
  u.id = m.owner_id and
  u.id = p.owner_id and
  u.id = s.owner_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: We generally prefer to use ANSI JOIN syntax in answers.

Comment: That makes sense Ke - I'll give it a try.  What if one of the subselects is more picky, like: (select count(*) from transactions where amount > 1000 and user_id = u.id) as big_transactions

Comment: just add to the WHERE clause: ... AND amount > 1000; if the restriction is on the group level, you can have HAVING clause

Comment: Hm.. I'd be concerned that adding "AND amount > 1000" to my where clause would filter out whole users, rather than just reduce the number of big_transactions is displayed for the user.  I'll give it a try, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony: It would be great if you didn't accept an answer before giving it a try. This query can give wrong results. If e.g.`monkeys` and `speeding_tickets` each yield 2 or more matching rows, the resulting counts will be skewed. Also, if any of the 3 tables that you are matching against `user` has no rows matching the given `user.id`, you'll get no results even though the other two tables do have matches. If you had to modify this query and eventually managed to make it work for you, please consider posting your own version & accepting it. The accept mark on this answer is simply misleading.

Comment: @AndriyM You're right; I actually did try it and it didn't work as intended.  I actually found the root of the issue was bad/missing indexes.  Once those were fixed the query speed was trivial.